# why do people use extend in a module definition?

Tags: ruby

for example, the rubygem *Devise* has the following piece of code in `lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb`

```
    module Helpers
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern
```

why use `extend` here? Will `include` do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `include` will not do the same.

`extend` and `include` perform similar but distinct roles. `include` takes the instance methods of the included module and makes them available to *instances* of the including module. In effect, `include` inserts the included module as a superclass of the including (in fact, `#ancestors` will even show the included module).

`extend`, on the other hand, adds the methods of the named module to the receiver. In the case of calling `extend` during a module definition, that means that the "extended" module's instance methods will become class methods of the "extending" module. It's often used to import decorators (really just calls to class methods) into a class or module being defined.

So, in brief, the snippet above will take the instance methods of `ActiveSupport::Concern` and make them class methods of `Helpers`.

Comment: and, could you explain more about **decorators**. What's that exactly?

Comment: `attr_accessor` and friends are decorators, as are `has_many`, `belongs_to` etc. from Rails. It's a generic term for what are technically method calls when defining a class to add certain functionality to it. They tend to look just like statements about the class.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, [`Object#extend`](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/core/Object%3aextend) is just:

```
class Object
  def extend(*ms)
    ms.each do |m|
      class << self
        include m # Obviously, this won't work since m isn't in scope
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So, it's easy to see that they are obviously *not* the same, since the methods end up in different classes.

---

A *working*, but less obvious version of `Object#extend` would be:

```
class Object
  def extend(*ms)
    ms.each do |m|
      singleton_class.send :include, m # Because Module#include is private
    end
  end
end
```